# cannot find where slf4j logs are displayed while using spring boot in IntelliJ community edition

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-boot, slf4j

I am new to server side programming and just trying my hands on Spring boot.
The following is my simple Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "controller")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        logger.error("Message logged at ERROR level");
        logger.warn("Message logged at WARN level");
        logger.info("Message logged at INFO level");
        logger.debug("Message logged at DEBUG level");



        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }

}
```

I am using gradle for project build.
After starting the gradle boot run, a sample GET request is working fine, but I cannot find the log.
Where is the log printed?
Am I doing something wrong or missing out something? 
Do I have to write something in the application.yml or logback.xml to use the default logger in spring boot?

Comment: SL4J is not a logging framework but a facade (an abstraction layer) for one of them. Usually, the de facto standard is to use Logback but you could use Log4J for instance.
I think Spring Boot, uses logback, but you have to check which library is getting embedded in your app to be sure, if you don't see logback (or any other logging framework).

Comment: If you use logback, and you don't have a logback.xml config file alrready in your app, it will use the basic configurator which I think write the logs to the standard output (your console if you're running it from IntelliJ)

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the response. Spring boot uses logback but I cannot find where the messages are logged. The "message" tab is even not displayed. Is it a problem with IntelliJ?

Comment: Probably a problem with your IntelliJ, when you Run your Spring Boot application from the IDE, it will open the "Run" tool window, and display console output there. At least you should see the Spring Boot logo in ASCII. No other configuration is required to use SL4J with logback.

Comment: @Debanjan were you able to resolve this?